# How do I give Rusty the Cooking class invite?

Tags: rustys-real-deal-baseball

In Rusty's Real Deal Baseball, I am trying to haggle him to unlock the next episode. So, I decide to talk to him, and the conversation gets to a point where he mentions Cooking classes to feed his children "fresh food." I offer him the Cooking class invite ticket twice, and he's rejected it both times. How can I proceed to giving him the ticket and getting a discount?

Answer (score 1):

Well, all you have to do is offer the ticket to him a few more times. Eventually, he will accept the offer and give you a discount that is over $1.00.